# Windows 7 Virtual PC VM 16 Bit Resolution

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc, resolution, 32-bit

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit with Virtual PC installed. My XP Virtual Machine screen resolution has 16 BIT 1024*768. I can't get it it 32 BIT.

I've reinstalled the VM components but to no avail. Is this normal with Virtual PC?

Answer (score 4):

You can get 24-bit by modifying a Group Policy setting as detailed [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/virtualization/32942-i-got-xp-mode-display-24-bit-color-integration.html).

Comment: Great hack, well done, didn't know you could do that - thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a superuser.com question.
2. The virtual XP mode in W7 only supports 16-bit video with the current release.